# Tubular Solenoids and Arduino

Tags: arduino, power, solenoid, teensy

I am interested in using [this](http://www.electromechanicsonline.com/product.asp?pid=18) Tubular Solenoid at 3 DC voltage to operate in Continuous (100%) Duty Cycle. According to the specifications the solenoid can operate at a:

> Continuous (100%) Duty Cycle when supplied with voltages equal to or
>   less than 24 Volts DC, with an approximate Input Power of  2 Watts

- Can I successfully drive these types of solenoids using an
  Arduino UNO/Teensy 3.1?
- How can I make sure an Arduino can accept 2 watts?

Comment: Yes, I am interested in using a 3DC Voltage with Continuous (100%) Duty Cycle

Comment: take a look at http://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/SolenoidTutorial

Comment: If you really want to run it at 100% duty cycle, you don't need the Arduino.  Just connect it to the power supply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt that you'll get what you want, but let's run the numbers.

The solenoid can be rated for continuous operation, and will dissipate 2 watts. I note that the link you provided allows the specification of duty cycle and voltage, so I assume you're going to order the 3-volt, continuous option. You can calculate the current needed, it's just 2 watts / 3 volts, or 667 mA. And your Arduino will never provide that kind of current.

So you'll need a driver of the sort shown in the tutorial linked by Jim Dearden. However, that runs on 12 volts, so you'll need some modifications. First, the optocoupler will have to go. Second, the MOSFET will need to be one with a low gate voltage threshold. The IRF640 shown in the tutorial can require as much as 4 volts. If you go to Digikey and navigate to the MOSFET section, you can find MOSFETs with gate voltage requirements as low as 1 volt, so that is possible.

Comment: I just arrived at a very similar conclusion. Thanks for your input. I will need to go back to the drawing board... I have upvoted your answer!